# Android - JSON Parsing throws unexpected character exception

Tags: c#, android, json, parsing, exception

I am developing an android `c#` app, which gets the price (in `JSON` format) from a specific `url`, then it parse it to get the price. I have tried multiple method to do so, but every method throw a specific exception. Here is my recent one:

```
public string getprice()
    {
        HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/etc-usd");
        webReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        webReq.Method = "GET";
        using (WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                var array = JsonValue.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
                string price = array["ticker"]["price"].ToString();
                return price;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, sometimes it works fine, and sometimes it throws this exception

> system.argumentexception: unexpected character '<' at line 1 column 0

It have debugged my app for 19 times to test it, it worked fine for the first 15 times then after that each time it got executed, it throws the error above. I don't know why this is happening. Would you please help me ?

**EDIT**

I have used Fiddler to inspect the raw request as @Fenton recommended me. 
Here is what I have got[image: here]

Comment: How often are you hitting the API? Is it possible that you are being throttled, and when you exceed the allowed rate, they send you an error instead of JSON? Your code works fine for me and I never get an error. Here's the fiddle I was using to execute your code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oceuPV

Comment: @Rainbolt I am calling the `getprice()` function arround 10 times in a `foreach` loop. But the function `getprice()` is fine, it just throws this exception arround 25% of all attempts. What do you propose ? I don't mind replacing it with anew fonction, i just want to get the price without exceptions.

Comment: We need to see the response when the exception is thrown. If it's working 75% of the time, and you capture the response in fiddler and show it to us, then chances are you captured a good response. We need a bad response. Edit your code to use a try catch and log the response when an exception is caught.

Comment: @Rainbolt okay, i edited my code and added `try` and `catch`, here is the exception thrown during runtime, I caught it by a Toast message: `system.argumentexception: unexpected character '<' at line 1 column 0`

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause of this problem is that the response is not actually JSON.

The clue here is the `<`.

The two common causes for this are:

- The web API you call has an error, and the error page is HTML (thus, it starts `<`)
- The web API can return different data formats, and is sending you XML (check your accept header, and that the API respects it).

Inspect the raw request (for example with Fiddler) to see the actual response - or look at the raw response in debug mode.

Comment: I have downloaded fiddiler and checked the response of the site, I have added a screenshot of the result in my question. I have found nothing suspicious

Comment: Can I do a play-arround here and tell the app that if it finds an unexpected character like `<` to remove it and continue parsing ? Because it doesn't always get this unexpected character, the function `getprice` is working fine, it just throws this exception arround 25% of all attempts.

Comment: @Wassim01 if the API supplies a HTTP status code, use that to determine success, rather than play with the response. If it fails, re-try (ideally with exponentially delayes, jittered re-tries) until you get a success response.